# SCC Finding filter based on iso (or other) compliance IDs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, filter, version-control, firewall, standards-compliance

I need to filter out all Firewall related findings in SCC. I want to avoid hardcoding all the categories names from [here](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/concepts-vulnerabilities-findings#firewall-findings).
Instead I was hoping to find a common denominator for all of the firewall ones (and found this to be ISO A.13.1.1 Network Controls).

How can I create filter in SCC that would filter based on this parameter?

Below are examples of what I have already tried (but did not work)

- `source_properties.compliance_standards.iso = "A.13.1.1"`
- `compliances.ids = "A.13.1.1"`  <-- actually adding this to OR'ed filter expression seems to break the result

My expectation was to get a list of all the findings with ISO-27001 A.13.1.1 category ([most of the firewall related](https://cloud.google.com/security-command-center/docs/concepts-vulnerabilities-findings#firewall-findings) ones in short)

Additional notes/thoughts:
I am a bit confused in general with the way the JSON finding details are structured vs how to filtering fields are structured - is there a reason these two couldn't be aligned for an easier filtering and overall work with findings?